# Performance cost of creating ObjectContext in every method in Entity Framework v1

Tags: performance, entity-framework

While using .NET 3.5 SP1 in ASP.NET MVC application, the ObjectContext can have lifetime on one Http Request OR of a SINGLE method.

```
using (MyEntities context =  new MyEntities ())
{
//DO query etc
}
```

**How much is increased performance cost of creating ObjectContext in every method VS per request ?**

Thanks.

Comment: Good question. Some people mention generating views to increase performance while creating context, but I have no idea if the performance hit is while the app is first run or during every single creation of ObjectContext.

Answer (score 17):

The cost of creating the context is very low. However, using a new context means that you don't have any cached queries from previous contexts. You can work around this to some degree with view generation or CompiledQuery. See also [Performance Considerations for Entity Framework Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx)

On the other hand, keeping a context around for a long time means you are tracking increasing amounts of state information, which has a performance cost of its own.

In my opinion, however, the most significant cost of a context is code complication. Using multiple contexts tends to lead to confusing code. So I try to use one context per group of related operations, e.g. handling a single HTTP request.

Comment: "The query plan cache is shared across ObjectContext instances within the same AppDomain. You don't need to hold onto an ObjectContext instance to benefit from query plan caching." [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949853(v=vs.113).aspx#3%20Caching%20in%20the%20Entity%20Framework]

Comment: Yes, the considerations have changed since I wrote this answer 8.5 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I am using `EF6` and schema of 163 entities that are db first generated from oracle.

I am measuring Initialization times and time to get 100 records from indexed table.

**C# Test**

```
var times = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime, DateTime>>();
var carTypes = new List<CAR_TYPE>();
var j = 1;
while (j <= 10000)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;

        using (var db = new EcomEntities())
        {
            var contextInitializationTime = DateTime.Now;
            carTypes = db.CAR_TYPE.Take(100).ToList();
            var executionTime = DateTime.Now;
            times.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime, DateTime>(startTime, contextInitializationTime, executionTime));
        }
    }
    var averageInitTime = times.Average(o => o.Item2.Subtract(o.Item1).TotalMilliseconds);
    var averageRunTime = times.Average(o => o.Item3.Subtract(o.Item1).TotalMilliseconds);
    Debug.WriteLine("averageInitTime - " + j + " " + averageInitTime);
    Debug.WriteLine("averageRunTime - " + j + " " + averageRunTime);
    j = j*10;
}
```

**Results:**

```
                    Runs        MS                         Runs      MS
+------------------+-------+----------+-----------------+-------+----------+
| averageInitTime  | 1     | 134.0134 | averageRunTime  | 1     | 1719.172 |
+------------------+-------+----------+-----------------+-------+----------+
| averageInitTime  | 10    | 12.27395 | averageRunTime  | 10    | 160.3797 |
+------------------+-------+----------+-----------------+-------+----------+
| averageInitTime  | 100   | 1.540695 | averageRunTime  | 100   | 19.94794 |
+------------------+-------+----------+-----------------+-------+----------+
| averageInitTime  | 1000  | 0.281756 | averageRunTime  | 1000  | 6.121224 |
+------------------+-------+----------+-----------------+-------+----------+
| averageInitTime  | 10000 | 0.167058 | averageRunTime  | 10000 | 4.751353 |
+------------------+-------+----------+-----------------+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the underlying model small or large, simple or complex? The cost of initializing and using a new objectcontext grows with the size and complexity of the model. If you have a handful of entities, it is usually neglectable. If you have hundreds of entities then it can be significant.

See:
http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2008/08/entity-framework-instantiation-times.html
and
http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx